# окно авторизации в браузере

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как заставить браузер вы вести окно для авторизации, с помощью js? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё зависит от того, как реализовано это окно - вёрстку покажите (html+css). Оно скрыто изначально? По какому событию Вы хотите его показывать?

Comment: @humster_spb я полагаю, это стандартное окно авторизации хрома. Запрос на страницу должен вернуть статус 401 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 1):

Если ты хочешь чтобы это окно выдавал сервер, то создай файл `.htaccess` с таким кодом:

```
AuthName "Admin Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/user/www/private/.htpasswd #Директория до файла с логином и паролем
require valid-user
```

Потом по выше указанному пути создаешь файл `.htpasswd` с парой логин-пароль, только зашифруй пароль. Получится вроде этого `root:E3h02IPyMMmug`. Документация по этому делу [здесь](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html).